# Initializing part of function only once

Tags: c++, static, initialization, c++builder

I have a function with a small bit which I want to initialize once e.g.

```
void SomeFunc()
{
static bool DoInit = true;
if (DoInit)
   {
   CallSomeInitCode();
   DoInit = false;
   }
// The rest of the function code
}
```

If this function is called many times it leaves one unnecessary `if (DoInit)` which can't be optimized. So why don't I do initialization elsewhere like constructor? Because, logically this initialization code best fits inside this function and it is easier to maintain that way, despite the fact it will do unnecessary check every time.

Is there a better way to do this without resorting to using the construct in above example?

Comment: It seems like you want a class, not a function.

Comment: This function is already part of another class, yes, I could use class or struct but that might make it even more messy because of scopes of certain members. I agree it may be alternative to this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Why couldn't it be optimized?

Comment: Once the init is done there is no more need for `if (false)` anymore which never executes.

Comment: If this is inside a class, then it looks pretty dangerous.  Your static DoInit flag would have one instance per process, and not one instance per instance of your class.

Comment: By "can't be optimized", you mean the compiler can't remove the if altogether, that's true, but at least SOME compilers can deal with "this is likely to be true" or "this is unlikely to be true", which can help. Is this function called LOTS, and in a context were one (predictable) branch is really an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by building a class that calls initialization code in its constructor, like this:

```
class InitSomething {
public:
    InitSomething() {
        CallSomeInitCode();
    }
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
void SomeFunc() {
    static InitSomething myInitSomething;
    ...
}
```

The object will be constructed once, executing the `CallSomeInitCode` exactly one time.

Comment: Of course, the code actually generated by this is probably more or less identical to that given above, since the compiler will make an "if myInitSomething has not been set call constructor" piece of code. If "SomeFunc" is called a gazillion times in a tight loop, it would still add extra code - in that situation, having a separate intialization and a "in debug mode check that it's initalized" would make more sense.