# How to run code 1 time in a class c++?

Tags: c++, class

```
class GameObject {
      //Is this where i would put that code?
public:
      double locationX, locationY, locationZ, rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ;
      bool isActive = true;
      bool DestroyOL = true;
      const char* LFile;
      void FileL(const char* FileP);
      void location(double, double, double);
      void Slocation(int, double);
      void rotation(double, double, double);
      void Srotation(int, double);
      void Clone(double, double, double, double, double, double);
      void Destroy(void);
};
```

I have a class called GameObject and i want to run some code when someone first makes a gameobject? Ex: when someone types in `GameObject player;` I want it to run some code but only once for the entire programs runtime. Except i do not know how to do that? But say later in the code they say `GameObject cube;` I would like it to run again?

Comment: Once per instance or once for the entire run of the program? If it's the former that's what constructors are for. If it's the latter you'll need to give us a little more detail on exactly how you want it to work although I'm sure someone will suggest using a singleton :\.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious and will be subject to damnation.

Comment: You can do a one time 'init' using static members. This question shows a simple way how right in the question itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511815/initializing-part-of-function-only-once

Comment: I only want it to run once the entire time the program is running.

Comment: What about keeping a boolean flag to remember whether the code was executed already?